# VBA to copy a file from one directory to another

Tags: vba, copy

I have an access file that I regularly need to copy to another directory, replacing the last version.
I would like to use an Excel macro to achieve this, and would also like to rename the file in the process.

```
   fileName = "X:\Database\oldName.accdb"
   copyDestination = "Y:\dbstore\"
   newName = "newName.accdb"
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: By regularly do you mean once every x minutes?

Comment: No, I mean like a few times a day

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use the appropriate methods in Scripting.FileSystemObject. Then your code will be more portable to VBScript and VB.net. To get you started, you'll need to include:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Then you could use

```
Call fso.CopyFile(source, destination[, overwrite] )
```

where source and destination are the full names (including paths) of the file.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method

Comment: Compared to the other, simple solution with FileCopy, this solution seems to have the advantage that the source file can also be copied while it is opened (e.g. by MS Access), i.e. when it's "read-only".

Comment: It says Syntax Error while using fso.CopyFile ........ @Bathsheba

Comment: @paran just remove the parentheses

Answer (score 82):

This method is even easier if you're ok with fewer options:

```
FileCopy source, destination
```

Comment: Nice and simple, however when I use this solution and the Access database to be copied is opened, I get an "Access denied" error. This does not happen when using the FileSystemObject.