# CopyPaste in VBA

Tags: vba

I am very new to VBA. I try to copypaste a a worksheet to another worksheet with below code:

```
 Sub CopyPaste

 Dim Source As String
 Dim Destination As String

 Set Source ="\\D:\folder\source.xls"
 Set Destination="\\D:\folder\destination.xls"
 FileCopy Source, Destination
 End Sub
```

I mainly use the code provided in:
[VBA to copy a file from one directory to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943003/vba-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another)

however it gives object required error. I am stuck a this point.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are missing a backslash in between c: and desktop. Also, is your desktop folder in the root directory of your C drive?

Comment: I made them up instanteneously. Sorry for inconvenience, I changed them @Aiden Grossman

Comment: @JonsiBillups Did you instantiate the fso, like in the linked post? Show your code for FileCopy and specify what line you get the error on.

Comment: @Absinthe I  get the error in the row where I set Source = "path" which gives me an object required pop up. Other method does not give any error but I see a blank sheet in the destination excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` is only used to assign values to object-type variables.

```
Sub CopyPaste

 Dim Source As String
 Dim Destination As String

 Source ="\\D:\folder\source.xls"
 Destination="\\D:\folder\destination.xls"
 FileCopy Source, Destination
End Sub
```

Those two backslashes before your paths look odd though.

Answer (score 1):

The two backslashes would be used if you were saving to a network path e.g.

```
"\\servername\sharename\filename.xls"
```

The correct syntax for your code should be:

```
Sub CopyPaste
    Dim Src As String
    Dim Dst As String 

    Src ="D:\folder\source.xls" 
    Dst="D:\folder\destination.xls" 

    FileCopy Src, Dst
End Sub
```

Also as A.S.H stated remember not to use `Set` with string variables.

FileCopy has caused me problems in the past , so if you have problems you can try the code below as an alternative:

```
Sub CopyPaste
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim Src As String 
    Dim Dst As String

    Src = "D:\folder\source.xls"
    Dst = "D:\folder\destination.xls"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fs.CopyFile Src, Dst
    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is working when I delete Dim Section for Src and Dst

Comment: Don't use `Set` with Strings.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for the clarification, sorry I wasn't​ thinking straight last night and I was going from memory as I didn't have a computer with me.

Comment: That explains it :) The downvote is not mine btw. .. it should be retracted now.