# How can I copy files in same directory to another directory with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file named control.xlsx and want to make macro in this file so control other files in same directory.

I tried like below,

```
Sub control()

  name = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\*.xlsx")
  Do While name <> ""
   FileCopy name, ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\new" & "\" & name
  Loop

End Sub
```

but it doesn't work.. anybody who can help me!
I want to modify the copied excel files next. any tips!

Comment: Note that *"it doesn't work"* is a completely useless error description. Also make sure that `ActiveWorkbook` is exactly what you want and not `ThisWorkbook` they often get mixed up. • I also recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943003/vba-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another

Comment: Are you sure the full destination path exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA to copy a file from one directory to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943003/vba-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another)

Comment: Why not just duplicate the folder (with contents...)

Comment: @SolarMike Good idea, but this would duplicate all files not only `xlsx`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost OK.

```
     Sub control()
        name = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\*.xlsx")
        Do While name <> ""
           FileCopy name, ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\new" & "\" & name
           name = Dir()
        Loop
     End Sub
```